# String comparison in C. Buffer one against string literal

Tags: c, string, comparison

I have tired to compare string in such way:

```
 if(strcmp(buf, "AUTHENTICATE") != 0) {
```

My buffer contains "AUTHENTICATE" string inside it as you can see on debugger inspector. But the result is that strcmp returns value not equal 0. Why? 
[image]

Comment: just a wild guess: does `buf` contain the terminating `'\0'` byte? If there's any vital information in the picture, please provide it as text in your question as well.

Comment: what if you're comparing the empty buf? are you validating buf is not empty?

Comment: It contains. The example seems to work now. I made some clean, build several times and starts to work. So the above code works correctly!

Comment: Why don't you implement strcmp() by yourself, just the matter of rotating the loop.

Comment: pls provide MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @MichałZiobro, it bit dangerous to have such code in the production environment. You can't expect others to restart the device. However, its good to know the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Just as a reminder, `strcmp` is supposed to compare 2 strings, character by
>   character, and returns whenever 2 characters are different. In such case, the function returns the
>   difference between the ASCII value of the first one and the ASCII value of
>   the second one. If a `\0` character is met, it is the last evaluated
>   character of the string before the function returns.

I see 2 possible reasons why `strcmp` would return another value than 0 when you expect it to return 0.

1. If your `buf` is an user input, it may contain an ending `\n`, which the string literal "AUTHENTICATE" do not contain. *It depends on how you deal with the input*: what functions do you use, do you store the whole input into `buf`, etc...
2. your `buf` does not contain a nul terminator. Note that in this case, `buf` is not a valid string. Please note that `strcmp` will continue evaluating both strings until it finds a `\0` character, which means that if `buf` does not contain one, `strcmp` will keep reading in memory after the last character contained in `buf` was evaluated, which you certainly do not want.